# Rupee symbol in HTML

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have few doubts regarding CSS while i implimenting rupee symbol in my asp.net webpage:

Below is my code :

HTML:

```
<div id="container"><span>Rs.</span> 5000</div>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:‘WebRupee’;
    src:url(‘WebRupee.V2.0.eot’);
    src:local(‘WebRupee’), url(‘WebRupee.V2.0.ttf’)format(‘truetype’), url(‘WebRupee.V2.0.woff’) format(‘woff’), url(‘WebRupee.V2.0.svg’) format(‘svg’);
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
.WebRupee{
    font-family:’WebRupee’;
}
html > body.WebRupee {
    margin-right:2px;
}
html > body.WebRupee {
    *margin-right:0;
}
#container {
    width:500px;
    margin:50pxauto;
}
```

I want to get the rupee symbol in asp.net webpage..is there anything missing here?

This is the url which i referenced:

[Click here](http://www.design2core.com/myblog/css/how-to-use-new-indian-rupee-symbolwebrupee-on-your-webpage-or-blog)

Do i need to install anything in my system..?

Will it available for all users where my webiste used throught the world without installing anything in users(their) system?

Can I append the already existing CSS file(which is used for other div tags in my same html file where i using rupee symbol)
with the above code? in that case do i need to change the name in css and id in html #container to 
something else as i already have #container there?

I didnt see the above part over #container in CSS

:ie

```
@font-face{font-family:‘WebRupee’;src:url(‘WebRupee.V2.0.eot’);src:local(‘WebRupee’), url(‘WebRupee.V2.0.ttf’)format(‘truetype’),url(‘WebRupee.V2.0.woff’)format(‘woff’),
url(‘WebRupee.V2.0.svg’)format(‘svg’);font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}
.WebRupee{font-family:’WebRupee’;}
html>body.WebRupee{margin-right:2px;}
html>body.WebRupee{*margin-right:0;}
```

not revefenced for DIV in html ..is it like that or do i need to make it inside a class

should it be something like this ..

```
.rupee
{

@font-face{font-family:‘WebRupee’;src:url(‘WebRupee.V2.0.eot’);src:local(‘WebRupee’), url(‘WebRupee.V2.0.ttf’)format(‘truetype’),url(‘WebRupee.V2.0.woff’)format(‘woff’),
url(‘WebRupee.V2.0.svg’)format(‘svg’);font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}
.WebRupee{font-family:’WebRupee’;}
html>body.WebRupee{margin-right:2px;}
html>body.WebRupee{*margin-right:0;}
}
```

and i can call it like ..

```
<div id="container" class = "rupee"><span>Rs.</span> 5000</div>
```

What actually the difference between .rupee and #rupee??

Thanks for help in advance!!

Comment: How is this .NET related? It's a simply HTML/CSS thing... Edited+retagged.

Comment: Are you uploading/including the font files in your web directory?

Answer (score 13):

The new Rupee symbol can be rendered directly in html like this ₹. Type `&#8377;` in your source.

Answer (score 2):

## **HTML**

add span with class="rupee"

```
<span class="rupee"></span>
Rupee Symbol in html:- <span>&#8377;</span>
<br>
Rupee :- <span>&#8360;</span>
```

## **CSS**

```
.rupee{
    background-position:left;
    width: 10px; 
    height: 14px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJZ9m.png');
    display:block; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Rupee Image

[image: Ruppe Image]

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fZpXM/

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code is that you simply aren't defining the class of WebRupee on the span element.

```
<div id="container">

<span class="WebRupee">Rs.</span> 5000

</div>
```

In response to other parts of the question...

the id container isn't required for the class, all it is setting is the width and margin

> What actually the difference between
>   .rupee and #rupee??

.rupee is a class and #rupee is an ID

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use webrupee`s API  (http://webrupee.com/)

just include this

and then use Rs. 200

or you can use this in html  ₹ this code will print rupee sign.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<del>&#2352;</del>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use &#x20B9(₹) to show the Rupee Symbol. or Inspect the text i have written here.

Answer (score 0):

**For HTML**

Use `&#8377;` anywhere in HTML document.

**But if you want to use it through CSS:**

then use "\20B9" in the content member such as

```
.rupee::before{
content:"\20B9";
font-size: 2rem;
}
```